# PHP File Upload / Host System

Tags: php

I have currently made a script which allows uploading for files within our company.  I am looking to improve this script to allow for the directory of the uploaded file to masked within the download link (Don't really want people knowing the directory structure)  Is there a way I can encode the link and then once a successful upload is made echo out the masked URL available for our clients to download.

```
    <?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 

 //This is our size condition 
 if ($uploaded_size > 350000) 
 { 
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //This is our limit file type condition 
 if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") 
 { 
 echo "No PHP files<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
 if ($ok==0) 
 { 
 Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
 } 

 //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
 else 
 { 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 } 
 ?>
```

Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the code, but here is my strategy for implementing file sharing without giving away their location.

1. Create a file that takes as a parameter the name of the file to be retrieved. It's only purpose is to open the file and stream it out. It should know ahead of time what to do with the file, where to look for it, and how to return it(stream). Let's call it `getFile($filename)`
2. In your main PHP file, call the function and store the result in a variable:

   $file = getFile($_POST['filename']);

Now send the user the file, and he will be none the wiser about where it came from.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get what you are saying but I am absolutly stumped as to how to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script that the file bounces. It just accepts the filename as parameter. Something like:

download.php?file=myfile.txt

that way you don't say where you put your files, and it's easy to implement. You could add headers to actually download the file.